# Perl: Using split but ignore quotes

Tags: regex, perl, hash, split

I'm trying to create a Perl hash from an input string, but I'm having problems with the original 'split', as values may contain quotes. Below is an example input string, and my (desired) resulting hash:

```
my $command = 'CREATE:USER:TEL,12345678:MOB,444001122:Type,Whatever:ATTRIBUTES,"ID,0,MOB,123,KEY,VALUE":TIME,"08:01:59":FIN,0';

my %hash = 
  (
   CREATE     => '',
   USER       => '',
   TEL        => '12345678',
   MOB        => '444001122',
   Type       => 'Whatever',
   ATTRIBUTES => 'ID,0,MOB,123,KEY,VALUE',
   TIME       => '08:01:59',
   FIN        => '0',
  );
```

The input string is of arbitrary length, and the number of keys is not set.

Thanks!

-hq

Comment: In `$hash{ATTRIB}` value there are `MOB,123`. Where do they come from?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, use a csv parsing library.

Comment: Do you mean the key `ATTRIB` to be `ATTRIBUTES`?

Comment: My bad. I fixed the `ATTRIBUTES` confusion. So `$hash{'ATTRIBUTES'}="ID,0,MOB,123,KEY,VALUE"` and I fixed the `$command` string as well.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV). It handles comma separated value files correctly.</s>

### Update

It seems the format of your input is not parsable by the standard module, even with `sep_char` and `allow_loose_quotes`. So, you have to do the heavy lifting yourself, but you can still use Text::CSV to parse each key-value pair:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

use Text::CSV;

my $command = 'CREATE:USER:TEL,12345678:MOB,444001122:Type,Whatever:ATTRIBUTES,"ID,0,KEY,VALUE":TIME,"08:01:59":FIN,0';

my @fields = split /:/, $command;
my %hash;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

my $i = 0;
while ($i <= $#fields) {
    if (1 == $fields[$i] =~ y/"//) {
        my $j = $i;
        $fields[$i] .= ':' . $fields[$j] until 1 == $fields[++$j] =~ y/"//;
        $fields[$i] .= ':' . $fields[$j];
        splice @fields, $i + 1, $j - $i, ();
    }
    $csv->parse($fields[$i]);
    my ($key, $value) = $csv->fields;
    $hash{$key} = "$value"; # quotes turn undef to q()
    $i++;
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: The separtor is ':' and as far as I can see you cannot change the separator in this module..

Comment: @bliof: You can. See the `sep_char` option of the constructor.

Comment: My fault.. I searched for separator.. +1

Comment: -1: If you actually *try* this, you will see that you can't get it to handle fields like `TIME,"08:01:59"`

Comment: Indeed. This should be a tab-separated file.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see the most obvious candidate - `Text::CSV` - won't handle this format properly, so a home-grown regular expression solution is the only one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = 'CREATE:USER:TEL,12345678:MOB,444001122:Type,Whatever:ATTRIBUTES,"ID,0,KEY,VALUE":TIME,"08:01:59":FIN,0';

my %config;
for my $field ($command =~ /(?:"[^"]*"|[^:])+/g) {
  my ($key, $val) = split /,/, $field, 2;
  ($config{$key} = $val // '') =~ s/"([^"]*)"/$1/;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%config], ['*config']);
```

**output**

```
%config = (
            'TIME' => '08:01:59',
            'MOB' => '444001122',
            'Type' => 'Whatever',
            'CREATE' => '',
            'TEL' => '12345678',
            'ATTRIBUTES' => 'ID,0,KEY,VALUE',
            'USER' => '',
            'FIN' => '0'
          );
```

If you have Perl v5.10 or later then you have the convenient `(?| ... )` regular expression group, which allows you to write this

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

my $command = 'CREATE:USER:TEL,12345678:MOB,444001122:Type,Whatever:ATTRIBUTES,"ID,0,KEY,VALUE":TIME,"08:01:59":FIN,0';

my %config = $command =~ /(\w+) (?| , " ([^"]*) " | , ([^:"]*) | () )/gx;

use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%config], ['*config']);
```

which produces identical results to the code above.

Comment: That is very impressive. Thanks a million.

Comment: This is very elegant, again. I had no idea you can do it in a single line... I even do `chomp($command);` and `$command = s/;$//;`. I'll try to see if I can include that in your solution. Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) could handle. The `quotewords` subroutine will split the input on the delimiter `:`, ignoring delimiters inside quotes. This will give us the basic list of items, seen first in the output as `$VAR1`. After that, it is a simple matter of parsing the comma separated items with a regex which will handle optional second capture to accommodate empty tags such as those for `CREATE` and `USER`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @list = quotewords(':', 0, $_);
    my %hash = map { my ($k, $v) = /([^,]+),?(.*)/; $k => $v; } @list;
    print Dumper \@list, \%hash;
}

__DATA__
CREATE:USER:TEL,12345678:MOB,444001122:Type,Whatever:ATTRIBUTES,"ID,0,KEY,VALUE":TIME,"08:01:59":FIN,0
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'CREATE',
          'USER',
          'TEL,12345678',
          'MOB,444001122',
          'Type,Whatever',
          'ATTRIBUTES,ID,0,KEY,VALUE',
          'TIME,08:01:59',
          'FIN,0'
        ];
$VAR2 = {
          'TIME' => '08:01:59',
          'MOB' => '444001122',
          'Type' => 'Whatever',
          'CREATE' => '',
          'TEL' => '12345678',
          'ATTRIBUTES' => 'ID,0,KEY,VALUE',
          'USER' => '',
          'FIN' => '0'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash = $command =~ /([^:,]+)(?:,((?:[^:"]|"[^"]*")*))?/g;
s/"([^"]*)"/$1/g
   for grep defined, values %hash;
```

Comment: I intentionally left the missing values (`foo:bar`) undefined so you can distinguish them from empty values (`foo,:bar,`).

Comment: Thank you. This is great. How would you change it to allow empty values (e.g., don't need to distinguish)?

Comment: Why `s/"([^"]*)"/$1/g` instead of `s/^"(.*)"$/$1/` ?

Comment: Because I've allowed `"foo"bar"baz"`, so I need to dequote that.